# How to set Stanford-NLP simple API in french?

Tags: java, netbeans, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use stanford-nlp in french in netbeans.
I'm using netbeans 10.0 and stanford-nlp 3.9.2.

I'm using maven and I set this dependency in my pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.2</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.2</version>
    <classifier>models-french</classifier>
</dependency
```

And there is an example code in java.

```
Document doc = new Document(props_fr,"Ceci est mon texte en français. Il contient plusieurs phrases.");
        for (Sentence sent : doc.sentences()) {
            System.out.println(sent.parse());
        }
```

I expect the ouput to be (using http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/):

> (ROOT(SENT(NP (PRO Ceci))(VN (V est))(NP (DET mon)NC texte))(PP (P
>   en)(NP (NC français)))(PUNC .)))
>
> (ROOT(SENT(VN (CLS Il) (V contient))(NP (DET plusieurs) (NC
>   phrases))(PUNC .)))

But the actual output is:

> (ROOT (NP (NP (NNP Ceci) (NNP est)) (NP (NP (NN mon) (NN texte)) (PP
>   (IN en) (NP (NN français)))) (. .))) (ROOT (NP (NP (NN Il)) (NP (JJ
>   contient) (NNS plusieurs) (NNS phrases)) (. .)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to load the StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties?

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(IOUtils.readerFromString("StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties"));
StanfordCoreNLP corenlp = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

Annotation ann = corenlp.process("Ceci est mon texte en français. Il contient plusieurs phrases.");
Document doc = new Document(props, ann);
```

Comment: Thanks, it work by loading the properties an adding this: ```Annotation ann = corenlp.process("Ceci est mon texte en français. Il contient plusieurs phrases.");
        
        Document doc = new Document(props, ann);```